# Not enough space when running Hudson jobs

Tags: unix, memory, jenkins, hudson, solaris

My Hudson jobs are crashing on each run with this error:

```
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=12, Not enough space
     at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
```

I found documention on StackOverflow and on the Jenkins website regarding this error, which indicate a problem of swap space (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/IOException+Not+enough+space).

However, maybe my problem is different or not, but if I launch the process manually it works fine.
A weird thing is I see different resuls from top of from prstat:

Specs:

- Hudson processes are running in their own Unix user
- OS: SunOS dc5c00-d12 5.10 Generic_147440-19 sun4v sparc sun4v
- Memory:

  - from top:

    ```
    32G phys mem, 6255M free mem, 16G total swap, 16G free swap
    ```
  - from prstat

    ```
    NPROC USERNAME  SWAP   RSS MEMORY      TIME  CPU
    50 user1      12G   12G    39%  89:02:31 0.3%
    36 user2      11G 6779M    21% 155:17:41 0.0%
    26 user3      10G 8509M    26% 4787:37:4 8.0%
     6 hudson    572M  556M   1.7%   0:08:25 0.0%
    57 root      280M  285M   0.9% 138:46:05 0.0%
    ```

Can anywone confirm if I have a swap issue? top shows 16GB free...

EDIT: 
results from swap -s (after problem being remporarly resolved)

```
    total: 19940168k bytes allocated + 12578048k reserved = 32518216k used, 4118208k available
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly a swap issue.

`top` is reporting as free swap blocks that do not contain paginated data. However, even while unused, some of these blocks can be reserved (i.e untouched still allocated virtual memory). When you have no more blocks to back memory reservations, you got this "Not enough space" exception.

`swap -s` shows your applications are reserving more that 12 GB while your swap area is just 16 GB. I would double the size of your swap to prevent virtual memory shortage in your case.

Comment: Thanks, I just posted swap -s results. However yesterday I killed some application running under user3, and it is now consuming 7GB of swap instead of 10. The count is still not right though, since swap -s shows 4GB available. But at least it is working for now.

Comment: And I find it surprising that top shows that 100% of the swap is free... even if it is just reserved...

Comment: The various commands you are using are not measuring the same thing. What count is still not right ?

Comment: The numbers shown by swap -s and prstat are not the same. Howerver, it may very well be because of something else has been killed between those two days.   But top is the one that surprise me the most. Even if it is just reserved memory, this server is running Oracle DB, WebLogic Server, JBoss and Tomcat... i`d be surprised if no swap is really used but just reserved...

Comment: Please update you question with `swap -s` and `prstat -a` or better `prstat -Z` output run close to each other. There is no point comparing commands run within a 2 days interval. If you want to check if swap is actually used or not with a Solaris native command, run `swap -l`.